# pivot 2 columns and show data one after another in ms sql

Tags: sql-server, database, pivot

Below is my table

[image]

and I want result as below

[image]

through pivot I have achieved as below

[image]

this but still the column need to be one after other.

below is query that I have written

```
DECLARE @pivot1 varchar(8000), DECLARE @pivot2 varchar(8000)

SELECT  @pivot1=coalesce(@pivot1+',','')+'[cust'+cast(number+1 as varchar(10))+']' FROM  master..spt_values where type='p' and  number<=(SELECT max(len(cust1)-len(replace(cust1,',',''))) FROM xyz1)

SELECT  @pivot2=coalesce(@pivot2+',','')+'[city'+cast(number+1 as varchar(10))+']' FROM  master..spt_values where type='p' and  number<=(SELECT max(len(city1)-len(replace(city1,',',''))) FROM xyz1)

SELECT A.*, B.* FROM  (
        select p.*
        from (
        select 
            product,substring(cust, start+2, endPos-Start-2) as token,
            'cust'+cast(row_number() over(partition by product order by start) as varchar(10)) as n
        from (
            select 
                product, Customer, n as start, charindex(',',Customer,n+2) endPos
                from (select number as n from master..spt_values where type='p') num
                cross join 
                (
                    select product, ',' + Customer +',' as cust 
                    from 
                        xyz1
                ) m
            where n < len(cust)-1
            and substring(cust,n+1,1) = ',') as cust
        ) pvt
        Pivot ( max(token)for n in ([cust1],[cust2],[cust3]))p ) A JOIN (
        select 
            product,substring(city, start+2, endPos-Start-2) as token,
            'city'+cast(row_number() over(partition by product order by start) as varchar(10)) as n
        from (
            select 
                product, Customer, n as start, charindex(',',Customer,n+2) endPos
                from (select number as n from master..spt_values where type='p') num
                cross join 
                (
                    select product, ',' + City +',' as city 
                    from 
                        xyz1
                ) m
            where n < len(city)-1
            and substring(city,n+1,1) = ',') as city
        ) pvt
        Pivot ( max(token)for n in ([city1],[city2],[city3]))p ) B

ON A.product = B.product
```

xyz & xyz1 are views as below :

xyz view :-

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO

ALTER view [dbo].[xyz] as  select product, Customer, City from Customer with (nolock) where product IN (1,2)

GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO
```

and xyz1 view as :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO

ALTER view [dbo].[xyz1] as

    SELECT product, Customer, City  ,Customer1=STUFF    (  
        (  
          SELECT  ', '+ CAST(sh.Customer AS VARCHAR(MAX))
          FROM xyz sh
          where sh.product IN (1,2)
          FOR XMl PATH('')  
          
        ),1,1,''  
            )   ,City=STUFF     (  
        (  
          SELECT  ', '+ CAST(sh.City AS VARCHAR(MAX))
          FROM xyz sh
           where sh.product IN (1,2)
          FOR XMl PATH('')
          
        ),1,1,''  
            )       FROM xyz t1         where t1.product IN (1,2)

GO
```

Comment: select the columns as ur wish.. order doesn't matters

Comment: the I cannot specify column names in SELECT Clause as the column names are dynamically generated while I PIVOT.

Comment: can u show ur code ?

Comment: i have updated the question @Nithin

Comment: where is the views ? xyz and xyz1

Comment: @Nithin sorry the change was not updated .

Answer (score 0):

The columns come out in the order you specify them in your SELECT list.

If necessary, turn your current query into a CTE or derived table, and do an outer SELECT from it with the columns in the order you want.

Comment: I cannot specify column names in SELECT Clause as the column names are dynamically generated while I PIVOT.

Comment: Yes you can, you just have to dynamically generate the SELECT clause, the same way you dynamically generate the PIVOT.

Answer (score 0):

Try to select the table using cte(common table expression)

```
;with cte as (SELECT A.*, B.* FROM  (
        select p.*
        from (
        select 
            product,substring(cust, start+2, endPos-Start-2) as token,
            'cust'+cast(row_number() over(partition by product order by start) as varchar(10)) as n
        from (
            select 
                product, Customer, n as start, charindex(',',Customer,n+2) endPos
                from (select number as n from master..spt_values where type='p') num
                cross join 
                (
                    select product, ',' + Customer +',' as cust 
                    from 
                        xyz1
                ) m
            where n < len(cust)-1
            and substring(cust,n+1,1) = ',') as cust
        ) pvt
        Pivot ( max(token)for n in ([cust1],[cust2],[cust3]))p ) A JOIN (
        select 
            product,substring(city, start+2, endPos-Start-2) as token,
            'city'+cast(row_number() over(partition by product order by start) as varchar(10)) as n
        from (
            select 
                product, Customer, n as start, charindex(',',Customer,n+2) endPos
                from (select number as n from master..spt_values where type='p') num
                cross join 
                (
                    select product, ',' + City +',' as city 
                    from 
                        xyz1
                ) m
            where n < len(city)-1
            and substring(city,n+1,1) = ',') as city
        ) pvt
        Pivot ( max(token)for n in ([city1],[city2],[city3]))p ) B

ON A.product = B.product)

select product,cust1,city1,cust2,city2,cust3,city3 from cte;
```

Comment: if my data vary will it work ,like cust & city may vary , max can be 10 and min can be 1.